# Comparing the value of a column with the previous value of a new column using Apply in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe with these values in column A:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(A,columns =['A'])

    A
0   0
1   5
2   1
3   7
4   0
5   2
6   1
7   3
8   0
```

I need to create a new column (called B) and populate it using next conditions:

Condition 1: If the value of A is equal to 0 then, the value of B must be 0.

Condition 2: If the value of A is not 0 then I compare its value to the previous value of B. If A is higher than the previous value of B then I take A, otherwise I take B.
The result should be this:

```
    A   B
0   0   0
1   5   5
2   1   5
3   7   7
4   0   0
5   2   2
6   1   2
7   3   3
```

The dataset is huge and using loops would be too slow. I would need to solve this without using loops and the pandas “Loc” function. Anyone could help me to solve this using the Apply function? I have tried different things without success.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this I guess could be the following

```
def do_your_stuff(row):
    global value
    # fancy stuff here
    value = row["b"]
    [...]

value = df.iloc[0]['B']
df["C"] = df.apply(lambda row: do_your_stuff(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.shift()` to shift your one cell down and check if the previous value is smaller and it is not 0. Then use `.mask()` to replace the values with the previous if the condition stands.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
wt = StringIO("""A
0   0
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   2
5   7
6   0
""")

df = pd.read_csv(wt, sep='\s\s+')
df
   A
0  0
1  2
2  3
3  1
4  2
5  7
6  0

def func(df, col):
    df['B'] = df[col].mask(cond=((df[col].shift(1) > df[col]) & (df[col] != 0)), other=df[col].shift(1))
    if col == 'B':
        while ((df[col].shift(1) > df[col]) & (df[col] != 0)).any():
            df['B'] = df[col].mask(cond=((df[col].shift(1) > df[col]) & (df[col] != 0)), other=df[col].shift(1))
    return df

(df.pipe(func, 'A').pipe(func, 'B'))
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  0  0
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  1  3
4  2  3
5  7  7
6  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali. It almost work, but there is a mistake here. For example, if I have these values in A = [0,2,3,1,2,7,0] I would get B =[0,2,3,3,2,7,0] but I need B =[0,2,3,3,3,7,0]. I need to compare A to the previous value of B and not to the previous value of A.

Comment: Updated my answer. Now it should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali. Unfortunately the same problem persists. If I have these values in A = [3,10,9,7,5,3,2,0] and I apply the function I will get B = [3,10,10,10,9,7,5,0] but it should be B = [3,10,10,10,10,10,10,0]

Comment: Looks like a loop is necessary here. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].shift()
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x:0 if x.A == 0 else x.A if x.A > x.B else x.B, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Arya. Unfortunately it does not work either. For example, if I have these values in A = [0,2,3,1,2,7,0] I would get B =[0,2,3,3,2,7,0] but I need B =[0,2,3,3,3,7,0]. I need to compare A to the previous value of B and not to the previous value of A.

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution of Achille I solved it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
  
A = [0,2,3,0,2,7,2,3,2,20,1,0,2,5,4,3,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(A,columns =['A'])

df['B'] = 0

def function(row):
    global value
    global prev 

    if row['A'] ==0:
        value = 0
    elif row['A'] > value:
        value = row['A']
    else:
        value = prev
        
    prev = value
    return value

value = df.iloc[0]['B']
prev = value

df["B"] = df.apply(lambda row: function(row), axis=1)
df

output:
    A   B
0   0   0
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   0   0
4   2   2
5   7   7
6   2   7
7   3   7
8   2   7
9   20  20
10  1   20
11  0   0
12  2   2
13  5   5
14  4   5
15  3   5
16  1   5
```